# Married couple pretend to like each other due to crystal sculpture

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Years ago, I remember reading a short story (as I remember it) about a couple whose prized possession is semi-living crystal structure that is sensitive to their relationship; it grows and maintains its beauty as a reflection of how good their relationship is. Because they are so invested in their crystal, they act happy and content while secretly loathing each other... effectively, slaves to the crystal by choice.

I probably have a couple of the details wrong. I believe I read this in the late 90's or early 00's.

I'd really like to track this down. It predates Facebook (or social media in general) but feels like a great metaphor for couples that maintain an outwardly happy face.

Comment: I'm interested in this story too ~although confused the crystal only reacts to their outward expressions of love ? And not their real feelings?

Comment: A lot of the details are different, but this strongly reminds me of [Gemstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Collected_Stories_of_Vernor_Vinge#Gemstone) by Vernor Vinge. It has a sinister kind of feel to it and a semi-sentient gemstone that is the center of a relationship in it, but the things about them acting content aren't there.

Comment: It's been so long, thus this question in the first place. As I remember it, the crystal picked up on subtle physical cues, and the whole point was that the societal-imposed conformity was enough to fake the crystal.

Comment: There's a somewhat similar idea in one of the stories in J.G. Ballards "Vermillion Sands", where the "recordings" of a prior couple who owned a house starts to psychically impinge on the new occupants; forcing them into the same negative roles. But they can't delete the recordings, since much of the value of the house is tied up in them.

Comment: Sounds a bit like the early SF short stories of George R R R R Martin, before he got all dragony and killy. But probably isn't. Could will be that Vinge bloke. Sorry I can't be more helpful.

Comment: Come on guys. The erudite and literary Sci-Fi.SE community can figure this one out.

Comment: I'm thinking it was either in Karen Joy Fowler's Artificial Things or in Dan Simmons' Prayer To Broken Stones; both collections of short stories.

Comment: Don't see it here though: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prayers_to_Broken_Stones

Comment: I finally found a copy of KFJ's Artificial Things at Powells but the story wasn't there.  Maybe its in the Simmon's book, maybe in something else I was reading circa 2003.

Comment: Sounds very similar to several stories in 'Vermilion Sands', is it possible that it is one of the stories from this book and you are mis-remembering some of the details?

Comment: It is similar, but it is absolutely not in Vermilion Sands (I have a copy of that). There's the story about the house with the "ghosts" of the two movie stars in Vermillion Sands.

Comment: Not "Payers to Broken Stones"; downloaded an e-book copy and skimmed it.  Still searching.

Comment: Somebody else apparently looking for the same story: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/189991/sci-fi-short-story-read-in-a-collection-couple-with-crystal-tree-that-reflected

Comment: Hello @HowardM.LewisShip, I've set a bounty on your question. If you remember [any additional details](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/19561), now would be a good time to [edit] them in.

Answer (score 67):

This is ["The Synergy Sculpture" (1978)](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?95108) by Terrence L. Brown.  It was original to *Orbit 20* and never reprinted.

###### a couple whose prized possession is semi-living crystal structure that is sensitive to their relationship

> 'The Synergy Sculpture is not a toy. It is a sensitive scientific instrument designed to aid couples and groups in becoming more aware of their emotional interactions. The Synergy Sculpture measures emotional interactions among the two to ten people to whom the unit is tuned—not individual emotional states. It has been used successfully by hundreds of psychotherapists throughout the world as a monitor of the growth of couples and groups toward emotionally mature relationships!'

###### it grows and maintains its beauty as a reflection of how good their relationship is.

> “Right,” said Mary enthusiastically. “And the better the vibes between us, the more complex, colorful, and beautiful it gets.”

###### Because they are so invested in their crystal, they act happy and content while secretly loathing each other... effectively, slaves to the crystal by choice.

> “It’s so sensitive,” John said. “We destroyed it with our argument.” He turned to Mary. “I’m sorry, honey. I should have thought before I snapped at you.”
>
> “It’s okay, I understand.”

and

> “Let’s make love,” he whispered. He kissed her neck.
>
> “I’m tired,” she said, turning away.
>
> “Come on, think what it’ll do to the sculpture.”

Comment: well done! I'd vote more than once if I could. This is one of those unanswered questions that has always bugged me lol

Comment: @NKCampbell It bugged me too. I owe an immense debt to [James Davis Nicoll's review of Orbit 20](https://jamesdavisnicoll.com/review/worlds-away); I'd never read the story before his review.

Comment: Congrats! This was a unicorn question.

Comment: @OrganicMarble This was among the longest unidentified story-ID questions, wasn't it?

Comment: @Clockwork - Not even close, but certainly one of the most highly upvoted without an accepted answer

Comment: @Fuzzyboots Thanks!

Comment: Outstanding!  I've been bugged by this for years and honestly had gotten to the point where I thought I had made up the idea and only *thought* I had read it in a story.

I must have read the story around 2002 or 3, but was struck around 2009 or so by a friend's marriage breaking up, and the disparity between the strife and bitterness I knew was going on privately, and the kind of lovey-dovey things they were still both posting to Facebook.

Comment: I'm going to order a copy of Orbit 20 and try to verify that this is, in fact, the story I remember.  I honestly never expected to get an answer!

Comment: Wow, I missed that this had been answered! Indeed, I'd consider it the #2 "great white whale" of unanswered story-ID, second only to [Story where the number 3 is the monster?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2937/31394) which achieved the most-bountied answer on the entire SE network (!) and inspired a [meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7446/31394) and [blog post](https://thesffblog.com/2015/10/story-where-the-number-3-is-the-monster-finally-answered/). In case you missed it, the author of the story has just posted here too.

Comment: @HowardM.LewisShip please mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 36):

I didn't realize I had a certain fame! I am the author of "The Synergy Sculpture". Back in the 1970s I attempted to be a professional writer. This was my only sale, although I came very close on a number of other stories to markets like Analog, New Dimensions (anthology series edited by Robert Silverberg), and some individual anthologies like **Thanatos**, edited by Scott Edelstein. I wrote a lot in the evenings back then, after my day job as a psychotherapist in a community mental health clinic. That work was obviously the genesis of the story.

Fun to see that the story still has a little life!

If there are any out there who want to read the story, but can't find **Orbit 20** I would be happy to provide a digital copy. Not sure how that would best be handled through this forum, though.

Comment: I, for one, greatly enjoyed the story. I first learned of it here, then when James Nicoll reviewed Orbit 20 I realized it had been found.

Comment: `Not sure how that would best be handled through this forum, though.` Generally you exchange email addresses either through a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) or by putting your address on your profile page, then conduct whatever business you have over email.